# How to mimic the builtin help command within commands.Bot() to bot.tree?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What I want to do is trigger the bot command help that is included with `commands.Bot()` (e.g `/help` returns all slash commands registered, and `/help <command>` returns the description of that slash command).

**A portion of my code**:

```py
class MyHelp(commands.HelpCommand): 

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        if self.context.guild.id != master_guild:
          return
        names = [command.name for command in bot.tree.get_commands()] # iterating through the commands objects getting names
        available_commands = "\n".join(names) # joining the list of names by a new line
        embed  = discord.Embed(title=f"Commands ({len(names)}):",description=available_commands)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"  {prefix}help <command> (e.g {prefix}help {random.choice(names)})")
        await self.context.send(embed=embed)

    async def send_command_help(self, command): # I am in the process of making this work for slash commands
        if self.context.guild.id != master_guild:
          return
        if len(command.description) == 0:  
          desc = "No description provided"
        else:
          desc = command.description
        e = discord.Embed(title=command.name,description=desc)
        e.set_footer(text="Usage: "+command.usage)
        await self.context.send(embed=e)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command=MyHelp()) #help_command obviously not needed

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        try:
          synced = await bot.tree.sync()
          print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command{'s' if len(synced) > 1 else ''}.")
        except Exception as e:
          print(f"Error syncing commands: {e}")


@bot.tree.command(description = "Sends help")
@app_commands.describe(command = "Enter command")
async def help(ctx: discord.Interaction, command:str=None):
  await ctx.channel.send_help(ctx.command)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did some experimenting and found a working solution:

```py
@bot.tree.command(description = "Sends help")
@app_commands.describe(command = "The command to get help for")
async def help(interaction: discord.Interaction, command:str=None):
  if command is not None:
        for c in bot.tree.get_commands(): # Iterates through registered slash commands
          if c.name == command: # Checks if command iterated is the command requested
            command = c
            break
          else:
            continue
        try:
          embed = discord.Embed(title=command.name,description=command.description)
          await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        except AttributeError: # if command is not found
          e = discord.Embed(title="Error:",description=f"Command {command} not found", color=0xFF0000)
          await interaction.response.send_message(embed=e)
        return
  # ran if command is None
  names = [command.name for command in bot.tree.get_commands()] # iterates through all the names of registered slash commands and compiles them into a list
  available_commands = "\n".join(names) # joins the list of names with a new
  embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Commands ({len(names)}):",description=available_commands)
  embed.set_footer(text=f"  /help <command> (e.g /help {random.choice(names)})")
  await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What you mean is called *syncing* and its a necessary step for any app_command to work, including slash commands.

The easiest way is for you to make a prefixed (aka regular) command that does `await bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)` where guild is an object containing the guild you want to copy it to. This ensures that there is a copy of the command tree on the guild you specified.
If having a per-guild tree is not a problem you can also use `await bot.tree.sync()`  which will copy it globally

Your slash command is not correctly done, but even if it were, if you don't sync your command tree with discord, **it won't show the slash commands when the bot is up**

Comment: Perhaps I have not given enough detail. I have updated my post.

Comment: I'm checking the code on my machine right now, but still, you must do the syncing in order for your slash command to pop on the command menu, though, I still musty say, your variable ctx is causing me good amount of confusion. I'm deleting my previous comments as to not confuse anybody else

Comment: I think that for me to be able to make an accurrate statement apart from the syncing bit, I'm going to need to see more code than what you provided. If you can show (at least partially) your help class so I can make up my mind a bit it'd be appreciated

Comment: I have updated my post substantially. My apologies as I am used to prefixed commands and `ctx` is more comprehensible to me.